# Get FileDialog InitialDirectory

Tags: c#, .net

i am using a `OpenFileDialog` to let the user select a File. The Dialog somewhere saves the last Lookup Directory, and i want to extract it, is this somehow possible.

On the Startscreen of my Application i want the latest Lookup Directory to show all (valid) files.

Ofc i can somehow read it out when the user first/last used the Dialog and save it, but my Idea is that Windows HAS TO save it somewhere, so why not just use that. Anybody knows?

Comment: You could try turning off the RestoreDirectory property and then saving the current directory after the dialog is complete - that might be the final directory it uses - and then saving that yourself. Alternatively you could just take the directory from the file selected's full path and save that yourself?

Comment: i found the path somewhere in the registry, but i dont want to mess around with it. Didn´t know of the RestoreDirectory property, if it prevents the writing of the registry-entry, then im going for saving the path to App.config.

Answer (score 0):

What about the property `InitialDirectory`?

[Here you can find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) the msdn page in where you can read this:

> The InitialDirectory property is typically set using one of the following sources:
>
> - **A path that was previously used in the program, perhaps retained from the last directory or file operation**.
> - A path read from a persistent source, such as an application setting, a Registry or a string resource in the application.
> - Standard Windows system and user paths, such as Program Files, MyDocuments, MyMusic, and so on (which you can obtain using the GetFolderPath method)
> - A path related to the current application, such as its startup directory (which you can obtain using properties on the Application object).

Comment: I think he's asking how to read the default value that the dialog will use if you don't set InitialDirectory yourself, which he thinks is saved by the OS somewhere.